# How have a variable number of parameters for one argument in Python with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using `argparse` to propose a mapping option to the users of my script as following:

```
parser.add_argument('-m', '--mapping_strategy', 
                    help='mapping strategy', 
                    choices=['ZigZag', 
                    'RoundRobin'])
```

So I can use the script in this way:

```
> script.py -m ZigZag
```

I need now to provide a new mapping strategy where the user can specify a custom file describing the mapping. Thus I need now something like:

```
> script.py -m Custom /home/manu/custom.map
```

How can I acheive this with `argparse` ?

Comment: I am just guessing that you have to add another argument to the parser. You could take multiple parameters by adding a parameter nargs='+' to add_argument. For mapping strategy you have already defined your choices. But that would work if you run script.py -m ZigZag RoundRobin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could certainly use a simple `nargs="+"`, but this has a few drawbacks, the `--help` output gets a lot less informative. You have to do your own verification that `mapping_strategy[0]` is in `['ZigZag', 'RoundRobin', 'Custom']`.

Now, another way would be to require a `-p` parameter for the path to the map, and require that it is set when `mapping_strategy == 'Custom'`. You could also print out an "ignoring -p argument, only required for Custom mapping strategy" warning message if they supply it with the wrong mapping_strategy.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-m', "--mapping_strategy",
                    help='valid strategies: ZigZag, RoundRobin, Custom', 
                    choices=['ZigZag', 
                    'RoundRobin',
                    'Custom']
                    )

parser.add_argument('-p', "--path",
                    help='path to custom map file, required '
                         'if using Custom mapping_strategy', 
                    )

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.mapping_strategy == 'Custom' and args.path == None:
    parser.error('Custom mapping strategy requires a path')
if args.mapping_strategy != 'Custom' and args.path != None:
    print('Ignoring path parameter, only used for Custom mapping_strategy')
print args
```

You could alternatively use a custom class to validate your parameters. This code gives a much nicer help message, along with better warnings and error checking. It's a little brittle though, as I've duplicated the list of valid_strategies. That's easy to overcome though.

```
import argparse

class ValidateMapping(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, args, values, option_string=None):
        valid_strategies = ('ZigZag', 'RoundRobin', 'Custom')
        strategy = values[0]
        if strategy not in valid_strategies:
            parser.error('Invalid mapping strategy {}'.format(strategy))
        if strategy == 'Custom':
            if len(values) == 1:
                parser.error('Custom mapping strategy requires a path')
            elif len(values) == 2:
                path = values[1]
            elif len(values) > 2:
                path = '"' + ' '.join(values[1:]) + '"'
            setattr(args, self.dest, [strategy, path])
        else:
            if len(values) > 1:
                print "path to map only used by Custom mapping strategy"
                print "ignoring: ",
                for i in range(1, len(values)):
                    print values[i],
                print
            setattr(args, self.dest, strategy)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-m', "--mapping_strategy",
                    help='valid strategies: ZigZag, RoundRobin, Custom', 
                    nargs="+",
                    action=ValidateMapping,
                    metavar=('mapping strategy', 'path to map')
                    )


args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

Here's the help output:

```
$python mapping_strategy.py -h
usage: mapping_strategy.py [-h] [-m mapping strategy [path to map ...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -m mapping strategy [path to map ...], --mapping_strategy mapping strategy [path to map ...]
                        valid strategies: ZigZag, RoundRobin, Custom
```

Here's what happens if you supply only a -m:

```
$ python mapping_strategy.py -m 
usage: mapping_strategy.py [-h] [-m mapping strategy [path to map ...]]
mapping_strategy.py: error: argument -m/--mapping_strategy: expected at least one argument
```

Here's what you see if you type a -m Custom but don't supply a path:

```
$ python mapping_strategy.py -m Custom
usage: mapping_strategy.py [-h] [-m mapping strategy [path to map ...]]
mapping_strategy.py: error: Custom mapping strategy requires a path
```

Here's what happens if you give -m ZigZag and append a meaningless path:

```
$ python mapping_strategy.py -m ZigZag blah blah
path to map only used by Custom mapping strategy
ignoring:  blah blah
```

Here's what you get if you supply a Custom choice with a path including spaces:

```
$ python mapping_strategy.py -m Custom c:\My Documents
Namespace(mapping_strategy=['Custom', '"c:My Documents"'])
```

But who would use Windows, or have spaces in directory names? Heathens.

Here's what you get if you specify an invalid mapping strategy:

```
$ python mapping_strategy.py -m Foo
usage: mapping_strategy.py [-h] [-m mapping strategy [path to map ...]]
mapping_strategy.py: error: Invalid mapping strategy Foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your below line to:

```
parser.add_argument('-m', '--mapping_strategy', 
                     help='mapping strategy', nargs="+")
```

This will gather all the positional arguments in a list instead. It will also generate an error if there's not at least one to operate on.

Check out the [nargs documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#nargs)

Comment: Thank you. But in that case the user will be allowed to type anything after the -m option, right ? Or I should do the checking myself ?

Comment: @dkol do you have any other solution ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva sorry never tried choices with nargs :(